# WordPress which template for blog list? (If the layout for category.php is different and front-page.php is implemented)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the WordPress site I'm creating, the latest blog post list and the category lists have different layouts.

I can use `category.php` for the list of posts in a category, but which template in the default WordPress hierarchy do I then use for the latest blog post listing?

I want to avoid custom page templates as far as possible.

(`front-page.php` is being used as the template for the static home page, so I can't use `home.php`, as per "Note: If `front-page.php` exists, it will override the `home.php` template." on this page:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Answer (score 0):

The default template for the latest post is `index.php`.

I think you have set up a static page that us front-page.php template as front page in `Settings -> Reading`, isn't it? If yes, you can also set up a blog home page and that page will use the index.php template. Simply create a new page called for example "Blog", and set your Settings -> Reading like this:

[image]

Comment: Using index.php doesn't work as the latest blog posts gets displayed using category.php. And the site has different layouts for the blog listing and the category listing pages.

Comment: But you said "I can use category.php for the list of posts in a category, but which template in the default WordPress hierarchy do I then use for the latest blog post listing?" I think I don't understand well your question...